# Click checkbox that changes name

Tags: macos, checkbox, click, applescript

I'd like to click a checkbox that changes name (it's called either "checkbox 3" or "checkbox 4", so I can't rely on its name).

I've tried with something like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Aycons"
    set theCheckbox to checkbox "checkbox 3" of window 1
    tell theCheckbox
        if not (its value as boolean) then click theCheckbox
    end tell
end tell
```

Unfortunately it doesn't fit my needs.

This are the attributes of the checkbox, any thoughts on how can I click it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Reference as an index instead, it should not change but may not be in obvious linear order.

eg,

```
set theCheckbox to checkbox 2 of window 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the valid input, but unfortunately I can't accept it since I can't refer to the checkbox by calling it "2" or "3" because it changes its name.

Comment: Hey @Giorgio, using a number instead of a string is different. Try my code, changing the number (2) until it successfully clicks your target checkbox. It's name should be irrelevant.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes the number is (2) sometimes the number is (3). So I can't rely on that! It depends on how many checkboxes are there at a given time.

Comment: Ok, so with the names, when it is called "checkbox 3" is there another checkbox called "checkbox 4" at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Maybe I can give it a try if you edit the code!